# ¿cual es la lógica detrás de esta función para ordenar números de un array?

Tags: javascript

encontré este código para ordenar de menor a mayor los números de un arreglo, pero, no entiendo la lógica detrás de la función que se le esta pasando a sort(), ¿por que ordena los números?

```
var arrayNumbers = [10, 8, 9, 5, 3, 78, 23]


console.log(arrayNumbers.sort(function (a, b){
    return a - b;
}))
```

Comment: Es necesario investigar antes de preguntar... en este caso, te habría valido con una rapidísima búsqueda en google indicando *"javascript sort"* y echando un vistazo a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), especialmente a la table de valores que devuelve la función utilizada para ordenar por defecto, donde se especifica que si el valor devuelto es negativo pone `a` antes que `b`, y si es positivo pone `b` antes que `a` en el array a devolver... Si quieres aprender a programar, te recomiendo aprender a usar documentación

Comment: La lógica es simple: dados 2 números, su resta es positiva, negativa o cero, basados en este resultado, uno de los números es mayor, igual o menor que el otro, eso establece el orden. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

El método `sort()` ordena los elementos de un arreglo y devuelve el arreglo ordenado.

Por ejemplo, si queremos ordenar de menor a mayor, sería así:

```js
var arrayNumbers = [10, 8, 9, 5, 3, 78, 23]

console.log(arrayNumbers.sort(function (a, b){
    return a - b;
}))
```

Y para ordenarlo de mayor a menor, bastaría con invertir los parámetros:

```js
var arrayNumbers = [10, 8, 9, 5, 3, 78, 23]

console.log(arrayNumbers.sort(function (a, b){
    return b - a;
}))
```

Te invito que leas la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) si quieres ver a más detalle.

Comment: eh... pero nunca dijiste el porque... :/

Answer (score 0):

gracias por la ayuda! no sabia que la documentación podía ser muy útil para entender estas cosas!. En resumen, el método le resta al parametro "a" el parametro "b" y esta posiciona elementos si "a" es mayor o menor a 0 e igualmente con b! .

cualquiera que tenga duda acerca de como funciona exactamente, le dejo el link de la documentación de este método, ahí viene explicado a detalle! :D

[Documentacion Sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)